# How can I can improve raw JSON data in order to use it?

Tags: json

I'm trying to use some results exported in JSON of a script called "Mixed Content Scan" (it's a script in order to search on a website if there is some mixed HTTP/HTTPS content and if all your pages are ok in HTTPS).

I'm a beginner with JSON, I read and watched a lot of tutorials in order to understand how to structure JSON data but I'm stumbling on something.

Here is a sample of my data (first 3 lines) :

```
{"message":"Scanning https://mywebsite.com/","context":[],"level":250,"level_name":"NOTICE","channel":"MCS","datetime":{"date":"2018-10-05 23:48:50.268196","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"America/New_York"},"extra":[]}
{"message":"00000 - https://mywebsite.com/","context":[],"level":400,"level_name":"ERROR","channel":"MCS","datetime":{"date":"2018-10-05 23:48:50.760948","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"America/New_York"},"extra":[]}
{"message":"http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image.jpg","context":[],"level":300,"level_name":"WARNING","channel":"MCS","datetime":{"date":"2018-10-05 23:48:50.761082","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"America/New_York"},"extra":[]}
```

I know I need to wrap my data around some {} or [] (tried both), but I think I'm missing something, for example, every JSON data validator websites are telling me that I have an error between 2 lines when I add a "," when I try to have multiple results into it.

How can I upgrade this raw data in order for a JSON validator to validate it?

Thanks!

Comment: It could be helpful next time to include a screenshot of the error

Comment: There's nothing wrong with any of the lines, but if you want to put all of the lines in a validator at once, you should put brackets around it to make it a list. Try **[** {"message":"Scanning"...} **,** {"message":"00000"...} **,** {"message":"http://"...} **]**

Answer (score 0):

How's this

```
[{
    "message": "Scanning https://mywebsite.com/",
    "context": [],
    "level": 250,
    "level_name": "NOTICE",
    "channel": "MCS",
    "datetime": {
        "date": "2018-10-05 23:48:50.268196",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "America/New_York"
    },
    "extra": []
}, {
    "message": "00000 - https://mywebsite.com/",
    "context": [],
    "level": 400,
    "level_name": "ERROR",
    "channel": "MCS",
    "datetime": {
        "date": "2018-10-05 23:48:50.760948",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "America/New_York"
    },
    "extra": []
}, {
    "message": "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image.jpg",
    "context": [],
    "level": 300,
    "level_name": "WARNING",
    "channel": "MCS",
    "datetime": {
        "date": "2018-10-05 23:48:50.761082",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "America/New_York"
    },
    "extra": []
}]
```

Entries in an array need to be separated by commas.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for this, it was so stupid, I had a "}" too much at the end of the last ligne for "extra". That was simply that. Thanks a lot again for your quick answer!